# Old ecto migration failing to run because I added a new field to model schema

Tags: postgresql, migration, elixir, ecto

I have an old migration that updates the roles for a user in the roles array field.

This migration doesn't run anymore because today I added a field called `is_bot` to my schema.

Here's what my migration looks like:

```
def up do
  query =
    from(
      u in "users",
      select: %{id: u.id, email: u.email, onboarded: u.onboarded, roles: u.roles}
    )

  Repo.transaction(
    fn ->
      query
      |> Repo.stream()
      |> Stream.each(fn user ->
        cond do
          user.onboarded && user.roles != nil && length(user.roles) > 1 ->
            roles = ["test"]

            user
            |> Repo.update_all(set: [roles: roles])

          true ->
            IO.puts("User #{user.email} has no roles. Onboarded: #{user.onboarded}")
        end
      end)
      |> Stream.run()
    end,
    timeout: :infinity
  )
end
```

And my schema:

```
schema "users" do
  field(:email, :string)
  field(:roles, {:array, :string})
  field(:onboarded, :boolean, default: false)
  field(:is_bot, :boolean, default: false)
end
```

---

I thought by using a `u in "users"`, I would avoid going through my schema in my model, but it seems to be using it regardless.

Error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column u0.is_bot does not exist
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1406: DBConnection.prepare_declare/4
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:1270: anonymous fn/5 in Stream.resource/3
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:1433: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:806: Stream.do_transform/8
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:1433: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:591: Stream.run/1
(ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:576: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1275: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
```

How can I run this migration?

Comment: Have you checked if is_bot is a field in the db? How did you "add today to the schema?

Comment: If you added the field by hand in your schema and the db don't know the field it will fail

Comment: @SimonFranzen I added that `is_bot` field via much more recent migration file. The question still stands.

Answer (score 2):

You are abusing migrations for running seeds. What you probably should do, is to move the seeding code somewhere into `seeds/update_roles.exs` and use this alias for setting `ecto` up (in `mix.exs` file):

```
defp aliases do
  [
    "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run seeds/update_roles.exs"],
    ...
```

That way the database would be first completely setup to the modern version and *then* seeded with the data. Current code tries to use the schema which contains `is_bot` field to run the seed on the database that does not yet contain it.

Comment: That is the way to go!